# href with id of DOM element is not working with Angular

Tags: html, angular, navigation

I'm trying to implement sliding navigation using angular version 4.

```
<a href="#SlideTo" > Click </a> 
<div id="SlideTo"> This is div </div>
```

so , when anchor tag clicked it is realoading the complete page and rediercted to

**http://localhost:4200#SlideTo**.
any one can help

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#routerlink-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been through this problem before, and i solved it using this line.

```
<a [routerLink]="['./']" fragment="SlideTo"> Click </a>
```